# Combine multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have arrays like this
Array 1:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )
)
```

Array 3:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
    )
)
```

and more of them.
I want to combine them to this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
        [2] => 0
        [3] => -0.025
        [4] => 0
        [5] => -0.025
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
        [2] => 0
        [3] => -0.025
        [4] => 0
        [5] => -0.025
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => -0.025
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => -0.025
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0 // These (0-3) are 0 because the other two arrays haven't 3 in the first level
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => -0.025
    )
)
```

The arrays have a different number of entries in the first level. In the second level there are always 2 entries.
In the second level of the combined array the first two keys (0 and 1) should always have the entries from the first array. The second two keys (2 and 3) should always have the entries from the second array and so on. In my example there are 30 arrays that I want to combine.
If an array does have more first level entries than others all entries should have 0 as value.

I hope you understand this :)

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php ?

Comment: @Mike not for numeric index

Comment: Does the order of the elements in the output array matter?

Comment: The order matters and merge_recursive does not work.

Comment: Thinking aloud: each array has it's own inbuilt iterator (see `next`, `current`). If you had all the arrays stored in an array. Then it would be fairly easy to advance through the iterators one pass at a time. When they return false return a zero entry. When they are all false then you are done. I suspect it isn't a lot of code. Not elegant? i agree ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built it ;-/

[Working demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/557895)

#### Requirements:

Basically it is transposing rows into columns.

- the output columns all have the length of the longest array.
- The source arrays can have different lengths. Any empty entries are assumed to have a value of `array(0, 0)`.
- The output columns are converted into a single dimensional array. i.e. source value arrays are appended to the column array.

#### Explanation:

I decided to use the internal iterator that all arrays have. i.e. the arrays already can record there own state such as current position (row) that they are on.

After that it is just 'housekeeping':

- keep a list of which arrays still have entries to be processed. When none of them have then we are finished.
- record which output column ($mergedEntryNo) that we are creating.
- scan along each (row) reading entries for the current row.
- after each row: advance to the next row and record which arrays are active - if any.

#### The class (SimpleMerge) that does the work

```
class SimpleMerge {

    protected $sources = array();     // a list of arrays!
    protected $sourceCount = 0;       // useful

    protected $isActive = array();    // which of them have entries to process.

    public    $merged = array();      // output in here and public

    protected $anyActiveSources = false;

    // need a list of arrays    
    public function __construct(array $allSources)
    {
        $this->sources = $allSources;
        $this->sourceCount = count($allSources);
        $this->isActive = array_fill(0, $this->sourceCount, true);
    }

    // generate the output by scanning the arrays line by line
    public function generateOutput()
    {
        $this->generateInit();

        $mergedEntryNo = 0;
        while ($this->anyActiveSources) {

            // set the next output entries   
            for ($sourceNo = 0; $sourceNo < $this->sourceCount; $sourceNo++) {
                $this->addEntry($mergedEntryNo, $this->getEntry($sourceNo));
            }        

            $mergedEntryNo++;
            $this->nextPassAdvance();  
            $this->setIsActiveSource();
        }

        return $this->merged;
    }


    // ensure everything is initialized correctly
    public function generateInit()
    {        
        $this->merged = array();

        foreach ($this->sources as &$source) { 
            reset($source); // force internal iterators to the start

            $this->merged[] = array(); // empty arrays in the output
        } 
        unset($source);

        $this->setIsActiveSource();
    }    

    // add to output
    public function addEntry($mergedNo, array $values)
    {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $this->merged[$mergedNo][] = $value;
        }
    }

    // get the current source entry - will be array of zeroes if end of array
    public function getEntry($sourceNo)
    {
        if ($this->isActive[$sourceNo]) {
            return current($this->sources[$sourceNo]);
        }
        else {
            return array(0, 0);
        }
    } 

    // check and set which ones are still active and also indicate if any are active
    public function setIsActiveSource()
    {
        $activeCount = 0;
        for ($sourceNo = 0; $sourceNo < $this->sourceCount; $sourceNo++) {

            $isActive = current($this->sources[$sourceNo]) !== false;
            $this->isActive[$sourceNo] = $isActive;
            $activeCount = $activeCount + ($isActive ? 1 : 0);
        }
        $this->anyActiveSources = $activeCount > 0;
    }

    // advance iterators on the sources that are still active
    public function nextPassAdvance()
    {
        for ($sourceNo = 0; $sourceNo < $this->sourceCount; $sourceNo++) {

            if ($this->isActive[$sourceNo]) { // was last time
                next($this->sources[$sourceNo]); 
            }
        }        
    }    
}
```

#### Run it

```
// create and run the generator...

$mergeAll = new SimpleMerge($allSourcesList);
$merged = $mergeAll->generateOutput();
```

#### Output:

Note, there are no zero values in the input. The values indicate source table and entry number.

```
Outpt: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => -11.025
            [2] => 21
            [3] => -21.025
            [4] => 31
            [5] => -31.025
            [6] => 41
            [7] => -41.025
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => -12.025
            [2] => 22
            [3] => -22.025
            [4] => 32
            [5] => -32.025
            [6] => 42
            [7] => -42.025
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
            [1] => -13.025
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 33
            [5] => -33.025
            [6] => 43
            [7] => -43.025
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 34
            [5] => -34.025
            [6] => 44
            [7] => -44.025
        )
)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much - I'll try it!